# can't open eclipse internal web browser after set MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, gtk, eclipse

When I tried to open my `Eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2) Internal Web Browser`, I got the same error as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130980/swt-browser-no-more-handles-error) question, and after set `MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME` variable, I got a new error:

> No more handles [Browser style SWT.MOZILLA and Java system property
>   org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla are not supported with GTK
>   3 as XULRunner is not ported for GTK 3 yet] org.eclipse.swt.SWTError:
>   No more handles [Browser style SWT.MOZILLA and Java system property
>   org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla are not supported with GTK
>   3 as XULRunner is not ported for GTK 3 yet]   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4559)

[this](https://tronprog.blogspot.com/2012/05/eclipse-internal-web-browser-in-kubuntu.html) post from 2012 says to install `libwebkitgtk-1.0-0` package, however it's not found in my kubuntu.

following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37099810/java-xulrunner-error-in-eclipse-swt-in-ubuntu) question, I changed my eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.GTK_version
2
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

and I got a different error:

> No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path
>   (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4559)

How can I make the browser run? I really need it for developing purposes.

**edit:** config system versions:

```
$ plasmashell --version
plasmashell 5.16.5

$ kf5-config --version
Qt: 5.12.4
KDE Frameworks: 5.62.0
kf5-config: 1.0
```

Also:

```
Sistema operacional: Kubuntu 19.10
Versão do KDE Plasma: 5.16.5
Versão do KDE Frameworks: 5.62.0
Versão da Qt: 5.12.4
Versão do kernel: 5.3.0-40-generic
Tipo de sistema operacional: 64 bits
Processadores: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memória: 15,4 GiB de RAM
```

Comment: Please always provide the version number of your OS when asking questions because the answer may depend on that. For Kubuntu, the output of `plasmashell --version` and `kf5-config --version` would be useful as well. Click the **[edit]** link below your question to add additional content.

Comment: @DKBose thanks, I edited the question with these info :)

Answer (score 0):

The package for WebKit might have been updated to a new version in your current Linux Ubuntu distro. For example, as said here https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserlinux , it is called something like libwebkit2gtk. You might want to search for such a package with a package manager like synaptic or from the command line with `apt-cache search`